# change background color of components

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
/*code of app.css*/
.div-app {
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(./assets/background-image.jpeg);
  background-color: black;
  background-position: top right;
  background-position-y: 150px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* I can only change the background of my components from app.css by adding the background-color to the body tag inside app.css, here*/
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(39,40,41,1) 100%);
}

.container-app {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

/*however I can only change its background from the app.css in the body, not through my register.css file.*/

/*register.css*/

/*if i try add the background color in the tag .body-register where i have all my content dont work */
.body-register {
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.form-register {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(35, 35, 35, 1);
    border-radius: 1px;
    padding: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 450px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/*i have my app.js and I have my app.css file. */

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='div-app'>
      <div className='container-app'>
        <div className='content'>
          <NavBar />
          <WriteMachine
            text="Hello, I'm Camila Carvalho"
          />
          <div className='first-p'>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
              </p>
          </div>

          <div className='button-done'>
            <button>Done</button>
          </div>
          <div className='image-container'>
            <div className='Image-headset'>
              <img src={images[currentIndex]} alt="" />
              <h3 className='headset-h3'>{headsetName[currentIndex]}</h3>
            </div>

            <div className='contact-div'>
              <ul className='contact-ul'>
                <li><a href=""><BsFillTelephoneFill /> Phone</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><BsFillEnvelopeFill /> Email</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><TbMessageCircle2Filled /> Message</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><AiOutlineInstagram />  Instagram</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className='headset-button'>
              <button>See</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


//and I have my register.js file where I want to change its background and the register.css file where I style my register.js page.//

const Register = () => {
    return (
        <div className='body-register'>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmite} className='form-register'>

                <h1>Register</h1>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <span>Name</span>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name='name'
                            placeholder='Type your name'
                            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Phone</span>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name='c-phone'
                            placeholder='Type your phone'
                            onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>E-mail</span>
                        <input
                            type="email"
                            name='email'
                            placeholder='Type your e-mail'
                            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label id='select-country'>
                        <span>Country</span>
                        <Select options={countries} id='select' placeholder='Select your country' styles={customStyles} />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Password</span>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            name='password'
                            placeholder='Type your password'
                            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <button type='submit'><a href="/login">done</a></button>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Register
```

I'm creating a project in React JS and I have my App.js file where I use it as my home page, and inside it, I have routes to the Register.js page. For the App.js file, I have an app.css file and for the from Register.js, I have Register.css. I was trying to change the background of my pages, but I can only do it through the app.css file, where I use the body tag to style the background. However, this causes the CSS to leak into my Register page and I am unable to change its background in its own CSS file.

I would like to know how I can stop this leak or how I can change the background of my screen from register.js since from register.css it doesn't work.

Comment: where is your Register.css file ? and how you are using this (css) file in Register Component ?

Comment: why dont you add .body-register { background-image: url(./assets/background-xyz.jpeg); } in your css;

Comment: I think you simply use the ordering in the css. So, lets say by default, the body tag gets yellow color like:-

body{color: yellow;}

And later in the css, you can do for register-body:-

.register-body{color: black;}

In this way, if a page has register-body then the black color will effect, otherwise yellow color as a default.

Comment: @MadanBhandari my Register.css is specified below my app.css in the question.

Comment: @RonakBokaria I tried to do it, but without success. what continues to prevail is the body css of the app.css

Comment: @CamilaCarvalho make the `.body-register` full height & width. `body` is for whole app, if you want separate color for component, make outer most div full height & width then change color

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `.body-register` full height & width and change color

```
.body-register {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 background-color: black;
}
```